# No more stackexchange.com front page link?

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, stack-exchange-button

There used to be a link to http://stackexchange.com in the StEx-MuCo-SuDr. It read:

> Stack Exchange is a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites.

The link has been changed to go to https://stackexchange.com/sites, and now reads:

> Explore our sites

Upon further investigation, I couldn't find a *single* link to the front page. Not at the top, sidebars, or even in the footer. The footer! There are plenty of links to various pages on that domain, but none to the front.

Yes, you **can** get there by right-clicking on the logo and selecting "open in new tab", etc, but that doesn't seem very user-friendly. Moreover, my typical "open in new tab" is middle-click, which opens the menu instead of following the link.

---

**The question:**

Is it intentional that there exist *no* links to the frontpage, or just an oversight? If intentional, why? I understand that page isn't the *most* useful, but not having a link to it seems odd to me.

Comment: Hmm, middle click works for me on Firefox.  Maybe it's browser-specific?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's intentional.

When we discussed the new top bar, we decided we weren't going to add anything that we couldn't argue for as a new feature.

Nobody could come up with any good reasons why we would want to send somebody to the stackexchange.com homepage. We still deep link in places where it makes sense, though.

Comment: Don't misunderstand, I'm not saying it should be in top bar. I just thought it odd that it's not *anywhere* now, even in the footer with the other less-used links.

Comment: Fair enough, but what's the use case?

Comment: All of the "more" links in the footer go to SE.com, @Generic. There are similar links to purpose-specific portions of SE.com all over the place. The actual SE.com *homepage* is fairly useless, unless you've never been here before and are looking for a high-level description of what it is we're doing.

Comment: @JeremyTunnell Where can I find out about global tag filters?

Comment: It seems to me it would be the *same use*, a general overview of the network for people stumbling in from Google.

Comment: @Shog9: Hmm, I've found the SE home page pretty useful enough as a portal to the other stuff there, like hot / filtered questions and my network profile. (Admittedly, the global achievement box in the new topbar removes one main reason for visiting the latter so often.) That's why I have it bookmarked. And the home page loads a _lot_ faster than the "all sites" page currently linked from the top bar.