# What's the desired navigation path from the communities to the top site "StackExchange"?

Tags: discussion, top-bar, navigation

When browsing within one of my communities I sometimes would like to navigate back to the top site "StackExchange" (= http://stackexchange.com) to see the hot questions for example, but I don't see a proper navigation element for that path.

Doesn't it make sense to have this link in the top navigation as well? Or do I oversee something?

Comment: Clicking `More Stack Exchange communities` takes you to stackexchange.com/sites... And this is a dupe... just can't find it!

Comment: IMO worth starting a feature request asking to add a link to http://stackexchange.com/ in the footer, under "Other".

Comment: dup? https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210462/244519 , related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243483/244519 , dup? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239384/is-there-an-easy-way-to-get-to-www-stackexchange-com-from-any-of-the-se-sites

Comment: Thx @Dronehinge . You're right. But believe me! I really searched for it but didn't find that one.

Comment: @Dro wow, I missed that even though I have an answer there.... what a shame! :-D

Comment: @shadow-wizard so guys should I delete my question?

Comment: No, leave it so future search for dupes might be easier. :-)